# Data entered in sqlite gets deleted automatically on app restart in android pie

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-9.0-pie

SQLite data gone disappeared after restarting app in android pie.App is working fine on other versions but in android pie when you restart the app few last entries are not visible.Database is not completely empty as other entries are showing.

I have tried setting WAL mode false by disabling WriteAheadLogging which seems to work on some devices but the issue was not completely solved as some devices were still reprting problems so I tried to set PRAGMA journal mode to TRUNCATE but this also did not work.

```
 public myDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
 @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();

      Cursor c1=db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE",null);
      c1.close();
    }


    public static synchronized myDbHelper getInstance(Context context) {


        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new myDbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
         mInstance.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(false);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

Then in my fragment:
myDbHelper dbHelper = myDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

I am not getting any error messages ,it's just that few last entries are not showing as if they were not saved in database.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: did you hear about the Room library?. An abstracted layer over the SQL

Comment: Yes,but my app is build using content resolver.I have to convert it to Room which can take some time and I need to provide a fix now.

Comment: Post the code where you intialize the db

Comment: public myDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }Then in my fragment myDbHelper  dbHelper =  myDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity());

Comment: update in Question

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that the issue is directly due to WAL mode being on or not, but rather that you are perhaps not correctly determining ***the last few entries***.

Coding `mInstance.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(false);` will directly turn off WAL before **onConfigure** itself is called (see below)

The first thing I would do is to change

```
public myDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

to :-

```
private myDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

To ensure that you do not inadvertently get a *rouge* instance of **myDBHelper**.

You may also, as a temporary measure wish to add the following method to your myDBHeleper class :-

```
public void logMode(SQLiteDatabase db, String tagextra, String dbname, Context context) {
    Log.d("BUILD","Build is " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    File dbf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString());
    File dbfwal = new File(dbf.getPath() + "-wal");
    File dbfshm = new File(dbf.getPath() + "-shm");
    if (dbfwal.exists()) {
        Log.d("-WALCHK " + tagextra,"The -wal file was found an is " + String.valueOf(dbfwal.length()));
    } else {
        Log.d("-WALCHK " + tagextra,"The -wal file doesn't exist.");
    }
    if (dbfshm.exists()) {
        Log.d("-SHMCHK " + tagextra,"The -shm file was found an is " + String.valueOf(dbfwal.length()));
    } else {
        Log.d("-SHMCHK " + tagextra,"The -shm file doesn't exist");
    }
    if (db == null) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("LOGMODE " + tagextra ,"Database mode is " + csr.getString(0));
    }
}
```

This can then be used to ascertain if the mode AND also if the -wal and -shm files exist and have any data.

In short it can be usedto alleviate any concerns that the issue is due to WAL mode.

For example using the following approximation of you myDatabaseHelper class. However in addition to your code :-

- invocation of the above **logMode** method has been included at pertinent points.
- the onCreateMethod has been included to create a table and add an initial row.
- the constructor has been made **private**

So it looks like :-

```
public class myDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_USER = "user";
    public static final String COL_USER_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_USER_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COL_USER_EMAIL = "_email";
    public static final String COl_USER_PASSWORD = "_password";

    private static myDbHelper mInstance;
    private Context mContext;

    private myDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
        logMode(this.getWritableDatabase(),"CONSTRUCT",DATABASE_NAME,context); // Note will force an open
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        logMode(db, "ONCONFIG1", DATABASE_NAME,mContext);
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
        logMode(db,"ONCONFIG2",DATABASE_NAME,mContext);
        Cursor c1=db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE",null);
        c1.close();
        logMode(db,"ONCONFIG3",DATABASE_NAME,mContext);
    }


    public static synchronized myDbHelper getInstance(Context context) {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new myDbHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            mInstance.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(false);
        }
        mInstance.logMode(mInstance.getWritableDatabase(),"INSTANCE",mInstance.getDatabaseName(),context );
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        logMode(db,"ONCREATE1",DATABASE_NAME,mContext);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_USER +
                "(" +
                COL_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COl_USER_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
                COL_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," +
                COl_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" +
                ")");
        //Add a row when oncreate is called
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TBL_USER + " (" +
                COl_USER_NAME + "," +
                COL_USER_EMAIL + "," +
                COl_USER_PASSWORD +
                ") VALUES('testuser','testuser@mail.com','1234567890')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long addUser(String name, String email, String passowrd) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_USER_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_USER_EMAIL,email);
        cv.put(COl_USER_PASSWORD,passowrd);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        logMode(db,"ADDUSER1",DATABASE_NAME,mContext);
        return db.insert(TBL_USER,null,cv);
    }

    public void logMode(SQLiteDatabase db, String tagextra, String dbname, Context context) {
        Log.d("BUILD","Build is " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        File dbf = new File(context.getDatabasePath(dbname).toString());
        File dbfwal = new File(dbf.getPath() + "-wal");
        File dbfshm = new File(dbf.getPath() + "-shm");
        if (dbfwal.exists()) {
            Log.d("-WALCHK " + tagextra,"The -wal file was found an is " + String.valueOf(dbfwal.length()));
        } else {
            Log.d("-WALCHK " + tagextra,"The -wal file doesn't exist.");
        }
        if (dbfshm.exists()) {
            Log.d("-SHMCHK " + tagextra,"The -shm file was found an is " + String.valueOf(dbfwal.length()));
        } else {
            Log.d("-SHMCHK " + tagextra,"The -shm file doesn't exist");
        }
        if (db == null) {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode",null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("LOGMODE " + tagextra ,"Database mode is " + csr.getString(0));
        }
    }
}
```

The following is in the fragment's **onStart** method :-

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myDbHelper dbHelper = myDbHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
    dbHelper.logMode(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(),"FRGONSTRT1",myDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME,getActivity());
    dbHelper.addUser("Fred","fred@fredmail.com","password");
    Cursor csr = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(myDbHelper.TBL_USER,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    csr.close();
}
```

That is it :-

1. gets a myDBHelper instance.
2. calls the logMode method.
3. adds a row.
4. extracts all the data into a Cursor and dumps the Cursor.

## Testing

### Test 1

Uninstalling the App on an Android (emulator) with API 28 and running results in :-

```
2019-07-07 10:38:56.022 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.022 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG1: The -wal file was found an is 16512
2019-07-07 10:38:56.022 D/-SHMCHK ONCONFIG1: The -shm file was found an is 16512
2019-07-07 10:38:56.023 D/LOGMODE ONCONFIG1: Database mode is wal
2019-07-07 10:38:56.038 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.038 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG2: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.038 D/-SHMCHK ONCONFIG2: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.039 D/LOGMODE ONCONFIG2: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.039 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.039 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG3: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.039 D/-SHMCHK ONCONFIG3: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.040 D/LOGMODE ONCONFIG3: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.041 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.042 D/-WALCHK ONCREATE1: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.043 D/-SHMCHK ONCREATE1: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.043 D/LOGMODE ONCREATE1: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.054 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.054 D/-WALCHK CONSTRUCT: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.055 D/-SHMCHK CONSTRUCT: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.055 D/LOGMODE CONSTRUCT: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.056 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.057 D/-WALCHK INSTANCE: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.057 D/-SHMCHK INSTANCE: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.058 D/LOGMODE INSTANCE: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.058 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.058 D/-WALCHK FRGONSTRT1: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.058 D/-SHMCHK FRGONSTRT1: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.059 D/LOGMODE FRGONSTRT1: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.059 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:38:56.059 D/-WALCHK ADDUSER1: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:38:56.059 D/-SHMCHK ADDUSER1: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:38:56.060 D/LOGMODE ADDUSER1: Database mode is truncate
2019-07-07 10:38:56.069 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4f533b6
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _name=testuser
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _email=testuser@mail.com
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _password=1234567890
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out: }
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _name=Fred
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _email=fred@fredmail.com
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out:    _password=password
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out: }
2019-07-07 10:38:56.070 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

In this case, due to the line

```
logMode(this.getWritableDatabase(),"CONSTRUCT",DATABASE_NAME,context); // Note will force an open
```

being invoked before

```
mInstance.setWriteAheadLoggingEnabled(false);
```

The database is initially in WAL mode but the line `db.disableWriteAheadLogging();` in the onConfigure method changes the mode to truncate and commits the transactions in doing so (there are outstanding transaction in the **-wal** file as it's size is greater than 0, (-shm is basically a copy of the -wal file)) as per :-

```
2019-07-07 10:38:56.022 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG1: The -wal file was found an is 16512
```

The transactions have been committed as in all the subsequent output the **-wal** file has been deleted.

### Test 2

The App is rerun  (i.e. now with existing data) the output is :-

```
2019-07-07 10:52:11.722 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-07-07 10:52:11.812 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:52:11.812 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG1: The -wal file was found an is 0
2019-07-07 10:52:11.812 D/-SHMCHK ONCONFIG1: The -shm file was found an is 0
2019-07-07 10:52:11.813 D/LOGMODE ONCONFIG1: Database mode is wal
........... subsequent output the same as first bar times
```

Although the database is initially in WAL, there are no outstanding transactions (the only difference).

### Test 3

If the line `logMode(this.getWritableDatabase(),"CONSTRUCT",DATABASE_NAME,context); // Note will force an open` is commented out and the App is uninstalled and rerun :-

```
2019-07-07 10:56:23.314 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-07-07 10:56:23.437 D/BUILD: Build is 28
2019-07-07 10:56:23.438 D/-WALCHK ONCONFIG1: The -wal file doesn't exist.
2019-07-07 10:56:23.438 D/-SHMCHK ONCONFIG1: The -shm file doesn't exist
2019-07-07 10:56:23.439 D/LOGMODE ONCONFIG1: Database mode is truncate
........... subsequent output the same as first bar times
```

Then the first use *(as an open isn't forced before `db.disableWriteAheadLogging();` called)* results in the database being in TRUNCATE mode.

Comment: Changing from public to private in myDbHelper class causes following error in provider class:                                                                                       
 myDbHelper(Context) has private access in myDbHelper                             
            private myDbHelper mDbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mDbHelper = new myDbHelper(getContext());
        return false;
    }

Comment: @ANKIT, then that could well be the issue rather than WAL/Journal mode. You should be using the **getInstance** to get the mDbHelper instance. Hence why I said a *rouge* instance. What is pretty clear is that the cause is not in the given code.

Comment: Changing   public boolean onCreate() { mDbHelper = new myDbHelper(getContext()); return false; } to   public boolean onCreate() { mDbHelper = myDbHelper.getInstance(getContext()); return false; } resolved the private access error in provider class.But whether the real problem of some data not appearing has been resolved is yet to be tested as it happens sometimes and not every time the app is restarted,so it's difficult to test and it affects only the devices with android pie.